# how to create a virtualhost with DDEV on windows 10 with nginx-fpm?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualhost, ddev

I would like to access my localdevelopment running on host/laptop with a mobile device.

In the old days, when using a wampserver, I changed the apache virtualhost settings like something like this:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vlokken.ltd
    ServerAlias vlokken.*.xip.io
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/vlokken/web
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/vlokken/web">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        require local
        Require ip 192.168.178.10
        Require ip 192.168.178.19
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost`

Is this also possible while using:

- DDEV `v1.7.1`
- Docker Desktop `v2.0.0.3`
- Windows 10 Eduction

DDEV.config.yml:

`APIVersion: v1.7.1
name: vlokken
type: drupal8
docroot: web
php_version: "7.3"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
mariadb_version: "10.2"
webcache_enabled: false
nfs_mount_enabled: false
provider: default`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your most direct question, I think you're asking "if using apache with ddev, how do I change the configuration", and the answer to that is in the docs: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-apache-configuration

But for accessing a local development environment from a mobile device, it's usually a little harder than just that, because the mobile device generally has no name resolution capabilities for a local network, or at least it's really difficult.

[This issue](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/375) explains how to set up ngrok, which will proxy your local ddev project to an externally (mobile) available internet proxy location. Give it a try.